# how to optimized sql query for speed up performance

Tags: sql, t-sql

i just have one sub query that just retrieves thousands of rows. here is my query :

```
str = "select * from ";
                        str += " (SELECT a.[ID] ,a.[strUserName], ";
                        str += " (select intCurrentBalance from accountmappings where intUserID = a.[ID] and intAccountType = 1) as Prm_Balance ";
                        str += " ,(select intCurrentBalance from accountmappings where intUserID = a.[ID] and intAccountType = 2 ) as Trn_Balance ";
                        str += " ,(select intCurrentBalance from accountmappings where intUserID = a.[ID] and intAccountType = 3 ) as Opt_Balance ";
                        str += " ,a.[strMobile] ";
                        str += " ,a.[strEmailID] ";
                        str += " ,a.[bIsApproved] ";
                        str += " ,a.[bIsActive] ";
                        str += " ,a.[dtlastrecharge] ";
                        str += " ,case when b.id is null then 0 else b.id end as createdbyId ";
                        str += " ,case when b.strusername is null then '' else b.strusername end as createdby ";
                        str += " FROM users a left join users b on a.intCreatedBy = b.ID ";
                        str += " ) as test ";
                        str += " where Prm_Balance < " + int.Parse(txt_balance.Text.Trim()) + " and Trn_Balance < " + int.Parse(txt_balance.Text.Trim()) + " and Opt_Balance < " + int.Parse(txt_balance.Text.Trim());
```

but this query takes too much time to display data. what resolution for this.

Comment: Check if there are indexes on the columns you  are using to filter and then check the execution plans, whether your sub-selects are performed before oder after reducing the set with the final where clause. You are using `Prm_Balance` there, which will need to compute all rows, before the set can be reduced... If you provide a [mcve] we might help you with a different approach...

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with input values.  I would also suggest that you provide sample data, desired results, explain what the query is supposed to be doing, and format the query as a *query* not as a *string concatenation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use single join for multiple account type and use `CASE` in the column selection as below

```
str = "select * from ";
str += " (SELECT a.[ID] ,a.[strUserName], ";
str += " CASE WHEN am.intAccountType = 1 THEN am.intCurrentBalance ELSE 0 END as Prm_Balance ";
str += " ,CASE WHEN am.intAccountType = 2 THEN am.intCurrentBalance ELSE 0 END as Trn_Balance ";
str += " ,CASE WHEN am.intAccountType = 3 THEN am.intCurrentBalance ELSE 0 END as Opt_Balance ";
str += " ,a.[strMobile] ";
str += " ,a.[strEmailID] ";
str += " ,a.[bIsApproved] ";
str += " ,a.[bIsActive] ";
str += " ,a.[dtlastrecharge] ";
str += " ,case when b.id is null then 0 else b.id end as createdbyId ";
str += " ,case when b.strusername is null then '' else b.strusername end as createdby ";
str += " FROM users a left join users b on a.intCreatedBy = b.ID ";
str += " left join accountmappings am ON am.intUserID = a.id
            AND am.intAccountType in (1,2,3) ";
str += " ) as test ";
str += " where Prm_Balance < " + int.Parse(txt_balance.Text.Trim()) + " and Trn_Balance < " + int.Parse(txt_balance.Text.Trim()) + " and Opt_Balance < " + int.Parse(txt_balance.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: can u please gives full logic as I questions.

Comment: Updated please check !

Answer (score 1):

One obvious improvement is to remove subqueries and use them in the `left joins` as follows:

```
str = "select * from ";
                        str += " (SELECT a.[ID] ,a.[strUserName], ";
                        str += " a1.intCurrentBalance as Prm_Balance ";
                        str += " ,a2.intCurrentBalance as Trn_Balance ";
                        str += " ,a3.intCurrentBalance as Opt_Balance ";
                        str += " ,a.[strMobile] ";
                        str += " ,a.[strEmailID] ";
                        str += " ,a.[bIsApproved] ";
                        str += " ,a.[bIsActive] ";
                        str += " ,a.[dtlastrecharge] ";
                        str += " ,case when b.id is null then 0 else b.id end as createdbyId ";
                        str += " ,case when b.strusername is null then '' else b.strusername end as createdby ";
                        str += " FROM users a left join users b on a.intCreatedBy = b.ID ";
                        str += " left join accountmappings a1 on (a1.intUserID = a.[ID] and a1.intAccountType = 1) ";
                        str += " left join accountmappings a2 on (a2.intUserID = a.[ID] and a2.intAccountType = 2) ";
                        str += " left join accountmappings a3 on (a3.intUserID = a.[ID] and a3.intAccountType = 3) ";
                        str += " ) as test ";
                        str += " where Prm_Balance < " + int.Parse(txt_balance.Text.Trim()) + " and Trn_Balance < " + int.Parse(txt_balance.Text.Trim()) + " and Opt_Balance < " + int.Parse(txt_balance.Text.Trim());
```

Cheers!!

Comment: i got this exception :     Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Ambiguous column name 'intUserID'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Ambiguous column name 'intAccountType'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Ambiguous column name 'intUserID'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Ambiguous column name 'intAccountType'.

Comment: it is because alias names of the tables were not used. Fixed it. see now